# Wrap lines at 80 characters

Tags: vim, text, macros, macvim

I want to break up lines longer than 80 characters into multiple lines at the same level of indentation as the original line. It should only make the cut at whitespace characters so that words don't get bisected. So, this:

```
 \begin{enumerate}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sed tempus odio. Phasellus lobortis suscipit mattis. Nulla facilisi. In nisi turpis, tristique ut accumsan at, sagittis a orci. Ut nisl enim, eleifend quis fermentum commodo, fermentum a velit. Maecenas a augue nec leo fermentum auctor et ut turpis. Donec ultricies ligula sed mi suscipit sagittis.
 \end{enumerate}
```

...would become this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
    sed tempus odio. Phasellus lobortis suscipit mattis. Nulla facilisi. In
    nisi turpis, tristique ut accumsan at, sagittis a orci. Ut nisl enim,
    eleifend quis fermentum commodo, fermentum a velit. Maecenas a augue nec
    leo fermentum auctor et ut turpis. Donec ultricies ligula sed mi suscipit
    sagittis.
\end{enumerate}
```

How would I write a macro to do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:set textwidth=80
```

or short hand form:

```
:se tw=80
```

Then mark the text and type `gq`.

Comment: That doesn't preserve the line breaks. It turns my example into this:  http://dpaste.com/829862/plain/

Comment: @JosephMornin - check out `:help formatoptions` and `:help fo-table` to see if any of those options might be applicable to what you're trying to do.  Specifically I think that `w` in the formatoptions might help you out as long as you don't mind wrapped lines ending in spaces.

Comment: Great, thanks—`w` was what I needed. For those who are curious, I did `:set tw=80 fo=tcqw`, marked the text, and ran `gq.`

Comment: I meant to only mark the text that you wanted to be reformatted, but @dash-tom-bang's suggestion is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You could type as follows or use `q` to record it.

```
:.!fmt --width=80
```